# Is the 20 minute wait between posting questions affected by reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, rate-limiting

I have to wait 20 minutes in between each question I ask on Stack Overflow. If I had more reputation would this period be lessened or removed?

Comment: Why are you trying to post questions so frequently? That doesn't give the first question enough time to get good answers and for you to evaluate those answers to find the best one and solve your problem.

Comment: It also probably doesn't give enough time to write a *good* second question. I'm pretty good at writing questions, but if it takes me less than half an hour from when I've initially thought I wanted to write the question, I can probably improve it further before posting.

Comment: I want to ask two different questions, sometimes you run into more than one problem in 20 minutes. I know its not smart to ask two questions in one post because then you run into a problem of having to decide who gets the correct answer, and if they both answered both questions then someone is going to get left out in the cold. Thanks for not answering my question ;)

Comment: You have three closed questions, one of them has been deleted. This should be an indicator that you should be taking *more* time do some research and write a good question rather than churn out a large amount of bad questions one after another.

Comment: I have asked far more good questions than bad, and nobody is perfect. Plus I joined this forum a month ago. That's why I asked this question. Is someone going to answer my question?

Comment: If you spent a minute searching you would have found this.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide which indicates that there is a rate limit of `Users < 125 rep, 20 minutes`.  The rate limit is there to encourage you to take time to do your homework.

Comment: @Zoredache Well that was a waste of two minutes!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question directly, I was able to submit two questions within two minutes, so apparently the rate limit on asking questions is reduced/removed at some point.  (Possibly when you're elected moderator.)

However, as indicated in the comments, it really does take some time to craft a quality question *that can be reasonably answered*.  (I had to tinker around the quality filter to get two questions in so fast.)  Twenty minutes is a reasonable time to wait.

Comment: Thank you for a direct answer, I feel like I have learned something now, thanks so much!